# Bitbucket REST API to set 'Branch deletion on merge'

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I know that 'Branch deletion on merge' can be set at both project and repo level via UI.

What I am looking for the the REST API endpoint for doing this. Similar endpoints for branching model, etc. exist but I could not find an endpoint for setting 'Branch deletion on merge' at project level.

Using Atlassian Bitbucket v7.17.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have `/rest/branch-utils/latest/projects/{project_key}/delete-after-merge`